# what is the difference between `doc.AddMember("key1",1,document.GetAllocator())` and `doc["key1"]=1`?

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0, rapidjson

I want to create a json object in `cocos2d-x 3.4` with `rapidjson` and convert it to a string:

```
rapidjson::Document doc;
doc.SetObject();
doc.AddMember("key1",1,doc.GetAllocator());
doc["key2"]=2;

rapidjson::StringBuffer sb;
rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(sb);
doc.Accept(writer);

CCLOG("%s",sb.GetString());
```

but the output is `{"key1":1} not {"key1":1,"key2":2}`, why?

Answer (score 0):

In old (0.1x) versions of RapidJSON, `doc["key2"]` returns a `Value` singleton representing Null. `doc["key2"] = 2` actually writes to that singleton.

In [newer versions of RapidJSON](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/releases) (v1.0.x), this behavior has been changed. It basically make assertion fail for a key that is not found in a JSON object, in order to solve exact problem you mentioned.

As a reminder, when an operation potentially requires allocating memory (such as `AddMember` or `PushBack`, an `Allocator` object must be appeared. Since `operator[]` normally only has one parameter, it cannot add new members as in STL. This is quite weird and not very user-friendly, but this is a tradeoff in RapidJSON's design for performance and memory overheads.